# uploading problem of wordpress theme

Tags: custom-post-types, themes

I have found a free theme for wordpress. But the problem is , when I try to  upload it in my wordpress site, the site says that style.css is not found. But in the zip file it is available. Where is the problem and how it activate this theme?

http://www.question2answer.org/qa/36095/update-minimalist-supports-responsive-mobile-tablet-supported?show=36184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a WordPress theme -- it's a theme for Question2Answer, which is a totally different project.